# Dependencies between sections

Tags: sectioning, input

I'm writing a document such as the following one:

```
\section{A}\input{A}
\section{B}\input{B}
\section{C}\input{C}
...
```

Each section provides some content but requires other sections to be included before. For example, B could require A and C, C could require A, and A could require nothing. In this case, the above piece of code should just put A and C in the output document as B is before C. I tried something with the ifthen package, but I failed to obtain a solution that doesn't produce a compilation error if the order is wrong. In particular, it complains about undeclared boolean variables, as it may happen I check for a boolean variable before the section that declares it is loaded.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: For something like declarations, why not take them out of the input files and put them in a common definitions file?

Comment: I don't really follow what it is you're trying to do. Why wouldn't your document have all of A, B, and C?

Comment: @TH.: it's just like dependency resolution for packages in a linux distribution, but for latex sections.

Comment: Hmm? You specify B but don't include it because it is not required by C, which comes later? That is not like any package system I know or can fathom. But given the dependencies you list, I could imagine wanting to output A and C if only C is asked for.

Comment: When you encounter a dependency, write it to the aux file. In the second run, check the aux file for dependencies and also include them. If there is a long sequence of dependencies, it can take a while to reach the stable solution.

Comment: @Aditya: good answer.  It would be cool to work this automatically into `\includeonly`.  But apparently `\includeonly` needs to be in the preamble, and the aux file isn't read until `\begin{document}`

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen: I specified B but don't want to include it because I specified it in the wrong place. It should have been after A and C. If one reads section A and then B, he will understand everything about A but nothing about B, because you need the background knowledge provided by C, which comes after. So it's better not to include B at all. C can be included, because the reader already read A, the only requirement. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Let me try to summarize your question: You want `\input{X}` to behave like `if (dependencies are already included) then (include section X) else (do nothing)`? So you want to set an `included-section-Y` flag on including Y and then check for that flag when including X?

Comment: @Caramdir: yes.

Comment: The answers provided until now are based on plain TeX, which I don't know. If possible, I'd like to know if there are LaTeX based solutions or packages to be loaded.

Comment: What dependencies are we talking about here?  Label/references and other counters? Because I have the same exact document structure (but the section declarations are in the input file) and all of that forwards fine (it requires two compiles though If I add a new label/reference)

Comment: @du9 you can use all TeX primitives in LaTeX as well, so I do not see where the problem is. If you want, you can but the code (with an appropriate header) into a .sty file and then include it with `\usepackage`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Caramdir's comment, this is how I will do this in ConTeXt. Perhaps someone can translate the solution to LaTeX

```
\unprotect
\def\markedinput#1%
  {\letvalue{@@input@@#1@@}\empty
    \inputgivenfile{#1}}

\def\checkdependency#1%
  {\doifundefined{@@input@@#1@@}\endinput}

\protect
```

Then use

```
\section{A}\markedinput{A}
\section{B}\markedinput{B}
\section{C}\markedinput{C}
```

and each file can start with

```
\checkdependency{A}
\checkdependency{C}
```

Of course, this cannot check future dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following work?

```
\let\sectionAincluded\relax
This is section A.

\ifx\sectionAincluded\relax
  \ifx\sectionCincluded\relax
    \let\sectionBincluded\relax
    This is section B.
  \fi
\fi

\ifx\sectionAincluded\relax
  \let\sectionCincluded\relax
  This is section C.
\fi
```

Here `\ifx` tests whether `\sectionXincluded` is defined and equivalent to `\relax` (instead of `\relax` on could use any other token).

EDIT: turning Aditya's answer into something non-ConTeXt-dependent:

```
%in main.tex
\makeatother
\def\markedinput#1%
  {\expandafter\let\csname @@input@@#1@@\endcsname\empty
    \input{#1}}

\def\checkdependency#1%
  {\expandafter\ifx\csname @@input@@#1@@\endcsname\empty\else\endinput\fi}
\makeatletter

% A.tex
This is section A.

% B.tex
\checkdependency{A}
\checkdependency{C}
This is section B.

% C.tex
\checkdependency{A}
This is section C.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after here is a topological sorting of your sections. This is actually fairly easy to do. Here's a fully LaTeX solution (no plain TeX macros used at all).

```
\begin{filecontents}{A.tex}
\depend{B}
\depend{C}
\section{A}
This depends on B and C.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{B.tex}
\depend{C}
\section{B}
This depends on C.
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{C.tex}
%\depend{B}
\section{C}
Uncommenting the \verb+\depend{B}+ causes a circular dependency.
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{currfile}
\newcommand*\depend[1]{%
    \ifcsdef{depend@#1}{}{%
        \ifcsdef{resolving@#1}{%
            \circulardependencyerror
        }{}%
        \cslet{resolving@\currfilebase}\relax
        \input{#1}%
        \csundef{resolving@\currfilebase}%
        \cslet{depend@#1}\relax
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\depend{A}
\end{document}
```

The `filecontents` environment just causes TeX to write these files out verbatim.

`\depend` checks if its argument has already been input. If it has, nothing happens. If it has not, it checks to see if it was in the process of being `\input`. If so, then there's a circular dependency that needs to be resolved. If it isn't circular, then it inputs the file and marks it as complete.